# Density pixels to pixels

Tags: android

In ImageView that have `android:layout_width="90dp"` and `android:layout_height="90dp"` I tried to set image with resolution 200x200 pixels and 350x350 pixels.

Image with resolution of 350x350 pixels was sharp, while image with resolution of 200x200 pixels wasn't that sharp.

Does anyone know how to calculate what resolution image should have to be sharp on ImageView?

This is important for me because I would like that thumbnails in my app look sharp, but I would also like that their resolution is as lower as possible because I'm downloading them from server and they should have small size.

Is there any recommendation for thumbnail size and for full size image, because original size of, for example, 3000x4000 pixels is way too much for full size.

Comment: You're going to have to read about different screen sizes and densities. See this link https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is well-explained in the [Iconography](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html) page of the documentation.

> Because you will deliver each icon in multiple sizes to support
>   different densities, the design guidelines below refer to the **icon
>   dimensions in dp units, which are based on the pixel dimensions of a
>   medium-density (MDPI) screen**.
>
> So, to create an icon for different densities, you should follow the
>   **2:3:4:6:8 scaling ratio between the five primary densities** (medium,
>   high, x-high, xx-high, and xxx-high respectively). For example,
>   consider that the size for a launcher icon is specified to be 48x48
>   dp. This means the baseline (MDPI) asset is 48x48 px, and the high
>   density (HDPI) asset should be 1.5x the baseline at 72x72 px, and the
>   x-high density (XHDPI) asset should be 2x the baseline at 96x96 px,
>   and so on.

In short, if you want an image for an ImageView that is **90dp x 90dp**, you would need:

- a *90px x 90px* image in drawable-mdpi (baseline, dp = px).
- a *135px x 135px* image in drawable-hdpi.
- a *180px x180px* image in drawable-xhdpi.
- ... and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the screen density using this:

```
float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
if (density > 4.0f){
    //it is a xxxhdpi display
    //load a extra extra extra high resolution image (600x600px, for example)
}
else if (density > 3.0f){
    //it is a xxhdpi display
    //load a extra extra high resolution image (450x450px, for example)
}
else if (density > 2.0f){
    //it is a xhdpi display
    //load a extra high resolution image (300x300px, for example)
}
else if (density > 1.5f){
    //it is a hdpi display
    //load a high resolution image (200x200px, for example)
}
else if (density > 1.0f){
    //it is a mdpi display
    //load a medium resolution image (150x150px, for example)
}
else if (density > 0.75f){
    //it is a ldpi display
    //load a low resolution image (100x100px, for example)
}
```

The resolutions I put, are a mere example. I put them there so you can have a reference of how much bigger the image has to be in order to keep it sharp.